# Laravel pivot table with multiple columns that needs to insert later

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am having two tables `routes` and `stations` and one pivot table `route_station`. See table details

### routes table

```
id, number, code
```

### stations table

```
id, name, code
```

### route_station table (pivot)

```
id, route_id, station_id, next_station_id, interchange_station_id, sation_order, distance, duration
```

`station_id`, `next_station_id`, `interchange_station_id` all are the `satations` table id

## Schema

### Station

```
Schema::create(
    'stations',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->index();
        $table->string('code')->index();
        $table->text('info');
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    }
);
```

### Route

```
Schema::create(
    'routes',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->smallInteger('number')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->string('code')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['number', 'code'], 'routes_unique_columns');
    }
);
```

### Route_Station - Pivot

```
Schema::create(
    'route_station',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('route_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('station_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('next_station_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('interchange_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('station_order');
        $table->float('distance');
        $table->integer('duration');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('route_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('routes')
              ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('station_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('stations')
              ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('next_station_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('stations')
              ->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->foreign('interchange_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('routes')
              ->onDelete('restrict');
    }
);
```

In the admin area, there will be a total of three sections to manage stations and routes.

1. Stations Page
2. Routes Page
3. A Page where I can add stations to route

That means I am not going to insert a record into pivot while creating a `station` or `route` but at any time later from the 3rd-page mention above.

I have two models now `Station` and `Route` and set the relationship as below.

## Station Model

```
class Station extends Model
{
    public function routes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Route');
    }

    public function route()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Route');
    }
}
```

## Route Model

```
class Route extends Model
{
    public function stations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Station');
    }

    public function station()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Station');
    }
}
```

So now the problem is that I don't know how to insert a record into the pivot table to fill out all the columns into the `role_station` table while `station` and `route` record already exists.

I have tried to use `attach()` but it is giving below error

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 1364 Field 'station_order' doesn't have a default value
>   (SQL: insert into `route_station` (`route_id`, `station_id`) values
>   (2, 4))'

So I need help with this

> #### Question:
>
> I understood the error that is asking me to set the `station_order` column value but I don't >know how can I pass values for `next_station_id`, `interchange_station_id`, `station_order`, `distance`, `duration`

Comment: If you have multiple relations between two tables, don't forget to specify with foreign keys are involved. Eloquent will go with the most easy and obvious, so `route_id` or `station_id`. I guess in the case of the relation `station`, it's for `next_station_id`, so put in next to the class name in the function in your Model. Maybe that'll fix some of your problems.
To add values inside your pivot table, use the `->withPivot()` function.

Comment: @Lyzvaleska thanks for your help. I have added migration code to the question. Reply to your input, I am not yet clear about how to add `next_station_id`. Will `->withPivot()` allows inserting an additional record to other columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, only the model keys will be present on the `pivot` object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Route')->withPivot('next_station_id', 'interchange_station_id', 'station_order', 'distance', 'duration');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood now this point. But I still have a question, how to insert all additional column values?

Comment: You should use attach()  function,

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships