# Laravel belongsToMany get pivot table additional attribute data

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have a `routes` and `stations` table that having relational pivot table `route_station`. I am able to fetch the relational data using `belongsToMany` perfectly.

**See migration and other details**
[Laravel pivot table with multiple columns that needs to insert later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317978/laravel-pivot-table-with-multiple-columns-that-needs-to-insert-later)

### Artisan output

```
>>> $stations = $route->stations()->orderBy('pivot_station_order', 'asc')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3097
     all: [
       App\Station {#3077
         id: 2,
         name: "Daugherty Fort",
         code: "LOGA",
         info: "Dolore blanditiis voluptatem recusandae eos. Et minus dicta culpa iusto et sequi fugiat. Et vel totam et earum. Ad consequatur qui consequatur distinctio dolorem modi consequatur. Est non id accusamus magni magni delectus.",
         photo: null,
         created_at: "2020-02-21 04:31:24",
         updated_at: "2020-02-21 04:31:24",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3105
           route_id: 1,
           station_id: 2,
           next_station_id: 3,
           interchange_id: null,
           station_order: 1,
           distance: 2.3,
           duration: 120,
           created_at: "2020-02-21 04:59:07",
           updated_at: "2020-02-21 05:01:15",
         },
       },
       App\Station {#3100
         id: 3,
         name: "Armstrong Green",
         code: "QWUB",
         info: "Eos enim reiciendis voluptas animi aut aliquid. Dignissimos incidunt placeat dolore. Magni et qui ipsam ullam dolorum numquam iusto. Eligendi impedit laudantium sint quia quam reprehenderit necessitatibus quos.",
         photo: null,
         created_at: "2020-02-21 04:31:24",
         updated_at: "2020-02-21 04:31:24",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3127
           route_id: 1,
           station_id: 3,
           next_station_id: 4,
           interchange_id: null,
           station_order: 2,
           distance: 1.2,
           duration: 95,
           created_at: "2020-02-21 05:44:04",
           updated_at: "2020-02-21 05:44:04",
         },
       },
       App\Station {#3128
         id: 4,
         name: "Monroe Locks",
         code: "FXNU",
         info: "Necessitatibus vero sed mollitia reprehenderit est repudiandae. Dolorem voluptas est similique amet molestiae consequatur.",
         photo: null,
         created_at: "2020-02-21 04:31:24",
         updated_at: "2020-02-21 04:31:24",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3092
           route_id: 1,
           station_id: 4,
           next_station_id: 5,
           interchange_id: null,
           station_order: 3,
           distance: 2.7,
           duration: 180,
           created_at: "2020-02-21 05:44:44",
           updated_at: "2020-02-21 05:44:44",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

> #### Question:
>
> However, I have an additional field in the pivot table that all
>   belongs to the `stations` table. I want to get those attributes
>   details. So do I have to create another station object to fetch data for `next_station_id` and `interchange_id` 
>   or there is any way using Eloquent to avoid creating a new station
>   object?

Comment: Your question is not clear about what are you trying to achieve. The question you linked seems to have answered it.

Comment: Do you want to access a pivot attribute from the station model like $station->pivot->distance?

Comment: What field is pivot_station_order?

Comment: Agreed Junaid, you just want to $route->attach($station, ['distance' => 2.8, 'duration' => 200])

Comment: You can pass what you want to store on the pivot table as an array for the second parameter in the attach function.

Comment: Or do you want to eager load the next_station_id?

Comment: @junaidrasheed  @AlexMac I want to get the station table's data for `next_station_id` and `interchange_id` which is also station id.

Comment: @AlexMac yes I want to load the next_station_id and interchange_id

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: This may not be able to be done right out of the box. However, in my mind you do it by creating a RoutesStaionmodel that extends pivot and then eager load that relationship. Though I would just use a package like https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations to achieve this.

Comment: By doing so you may potentially run into circular relationship where one station ends up loaded every other station so you would want to control the depth in some way to avoid that.

Comment: @AlexMac I see, so there is no way out of the box! Thanks for the reference package. let me try that.

Comment: Awesome best of luck

Comment: @AlexMac Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be able to be done right out of the box. However, in my mind you do it by creating a RoutesStaionmodel that extends pivot and then eager load that relationship. Though I would just use a package like https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations to achieve this.